# Hoxx vpn disabling other browser addons

Tags: vpn, firefox

installed hoxx-vpn addon on my ff browser (debian stretch) and created hoxx account through addon. Removed the addon shortly afterwards and realized other vpn addons would not work as usual - their icons and interfaces work, but my visible IP address is not that of the VPN.
Any ideas on what settings to check that hoxx might have altered - or if hoxx might have messed with my OS and not just with my browser?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Checked the profile on another OS - same result, meaning the issue is within the ff profile files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found it: if hoxx vpn addon is either disabled or uninstalled, it changes (at least) these 2 settings:

1. network.proxy.proxy_over_tls to false (true is default)
2. network.proxy.type to 0, even if another VPN connection is active at that time.

It's the former setting that is rendering the other addons ineffective - the other addons are not touching that setting upon install, since it's boolean type and the default value is the one they need.

I find this to be a very aggressive behavior from hoxx to do this.

Comment: Pedants will certainly have noted that this question turned out to be not Unix-related, but entirely a Firefox problem. My apologies, but this is something I did not know when I posted it - it could have been an OS setting as well.